# Can a machine have a name in Samba (for use on a Windows network) that is not the same as its hostname?

Tags: samba

This may be a very basic question, but I am not able to find a clear answer in the Samba documentation [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch07.html) or elsewhere on the net.  For various reasons I am attempting to give a Linux machine a different name as a Samba host - i.e. not the name specified in /etc/hostname).  Is such a thing possible?

In /etc/samba/smb.conf, it appears possible to specify the workgroup and the description, but not the name of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The setting is `netbios name`.